Swift Push ViewController from FlexLayout View
I basically followed the tutorial from FlexLayout on making a series of remote Views.
That part went extremely well... But I'd like to make the clicking on each of the individual views push a different ViewController.  I'm using tap gestures to make each of the views clickable... but neither love nor money will get them to actually take me to a ViewController.
If I try to present them I get:
Warning: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy

And if I try to push them I get some sort of nil error:
A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs.

Here's the code:
SocialView
import FlexLayout

protocol SocialViewDelegate {
    func didTapButton()
}

class SocialView: UIView {
    
    var delegate: SocialViewDelegate?
    
 
    
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

    fileprivate let rootFlexContainer = UIView()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .white

        let view1 = UIView()
        let view2 = UIView()
        
        
        let text1 = UILabel()
        text1.text = "Photos"
        view1.backgroundColor = .white
        view1.addSubview(text1)
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goEvt))
                //tap.delegate = self
                view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    @objc func goEvt() {
        //let vc2 = UsersViewController()
        //vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        //let vc93 = SocialViewController(coder: aDecoder)
        let vip = SocialViewController()
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "evview") as! EventsViewController
       // vip.present(vc, animated: true)
        vip.didTapButton()
}
        
        
        
     //   self.collectionView.addSubview(vc)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapAction() {
            delegate?.didTapButton()
        }

SocialViewController
class SocialViewController: UIViewController, SocialViewDelegate {
    func didTapButton() {
        let topdawg = EventsViewController()
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "evview") as! EventsViewController
        self.present(topdawg, animated: true)
       // navigationController?.pushViewController(topdawg, animated: true)
    }
    
    fileprivate var mainView: SocialView {
        return self.view as! SocialView
    }

For this part:
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goEvt))

You could put "goEvt" or "didTapButton"... One would keep you on SocialView, the other would take you to SocialViewController.  Doesn't matter.  You can also see that I've commented out a few things I've tried... It all leads to either the first or second error I posted above.
I can't make it to "EventsViewController" (or any other) no matter what I do.
So any help would be appreciated.
